# How to Include init.php (preferably on the 'init' WordPress hook)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, initialization

Hi I'm trying to add some code to allow custom meta boxes on my wordpress site:

github: https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

It states that I need to include the supplied init.php on the init wordpress hook, but I'm just wondering how to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: It also states: "*This script is easy to install. If you can't figure it out you probably shouldn't be using it.*"

Comment: Thanks to Mridul answer I now have some fantastic custom meta boxes. Thanks for your inspiring and wonderfully informative answer Vegar :)

Comment: This is part of the *very basics* of WordPress and also shown the `example-functions.php` file of that GitHub project. Which is pointed at in the third step of the installation process. Next time please perform some research/reading on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
add_action('init', 'include_init_file');
function include_init_file() {
    // use correct path here
    require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metabox/init.php';
}
```

the above code goes in theme's functions.php file. You have to correct the path to `init.php` file. The example above assumes the path as `[theme_directory]/metabox/init.php`